# How to bind a list of classes' property to a series of labels

Tags: c#, wpf, class, properties, binding

So, searching did no help and I'm kind of new to binding world.

to simplify it as much as I can:
I have 2 windows and a class. In the first window I declare a list of my class globally: `List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();`

The class supports INotifyPropertyChanged using PropertyChanged.Fody Nuget package.

```
class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

In the first window, I have a textbox and a button.
when I press the button, a new MyClass with the FirstName property of TextBox.Text is added to MyList. Then a new row is added to the second window's main grid and a label is added to the new row:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass mc = new MyClass() { FirstName = TextBox.Text; };
    MyList.Add(mc);

    //find my second window and add row and label to its grid
    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (window.GetType() == typeof(SecondWindow))
        {
            Grid mgrid = (window as SecondWindow).MainGrid;
            mgrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

            Label FN = new Label()
                {
                    Name = "lbl" + mc.FirstName,
                    Content = mc.FirstName,
                };

            mgrid.Children.Add(FN);
            Grid.SetRow(FN, mgrid.RowDefinitions.Count - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the code above, I know I should change `Content = mc.FirstName` somehow to keep it binded to the class property, but have no idea how, and searching didn't exactly help me solve it.

Anyone has an idea what I should do?

Comment: Search the web for MVVM and read some articles about this pattern. Then create a view model class with an `ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyList` property. Assign the DataContext of both Windows to the same view model instance. In the window that is supposed to show the list, use an ItemsControl (or a ListBox, ListView or DataGrid) and bind its ItemsSource property to MyList. Add an ICommand to the view model which adds an elements to MyList. Bind the Button in the other window to that command.

Comment: Before doing all this, thoroughly read [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) and [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview). What you have right now is a completely wrong approach. In WPF you are typically not supposed to create UI elements in code behind. Throw away your code and start over with MVVM.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a binding in code behind with something like this:

```
 Label label = new Label() {
     Name = "lbl" + mc.FirstName
 };
 Binding binding = new Binding()
 {
      Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
      UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
      Path = new PropertyPath("FirstName")
 };
 label.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);
```

Comment: `Mode=TwoWay` (and hence also `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`) is entirely pointless in a Binding of a Label's Content property. The control never actively updates its own Content. Besides that, the Binding is missing a source object (i.e. DataContext, Source, RelativeSource or ElementName).

Comment: Correct, my bad. I have just picked this from my project where I use this snipplet for a TextBox and failed to think for a second to realize it is a Label.